# Encode Base64 and send as attachment

Tags: node.js, base64, decode, attachment, nodemailer

This is example structure of **file**:

```
file:
   [ { container:'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0x ...,
       filename: 'logofinal.psd',
       mimetype: 'application/pdf',
       file_type: 'random'}]
```

How can I send it as attachment in **nodemailer**, i added:

```
  attachments: [
    { 
      filename: mailData.file.filename,
      content: mailData.file.container,
      contentType: mailData.file.mimetype,
      encoding: 'base64'
    }
  ]
```

Maybe i need a buffer to remove header from file.container?

However i do not have an idea how to resolve for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to send an email with an attachment file.
- You have the base64 data, and you want to send it as the attachment file.
- You want to achieve this using nodemailer.
- You have already been able to get and send emails using nodemailer with Gmail API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the base64 data is directly sent using the nodemailer.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

```
attachments: [
  { 
    filename: mailData.file.filename,
    content: content: /data:.*;base64,/.test(mailData.file.container) ? mailData.file.container.split(",")[1] : mailData.file.container,
    contentType: mailData.file.mimetype,
    encoding: 'base64'
  }
]
```

- If the header of base64 data (it's like `data:application/pdf;base64,`) is always included, you can also modify to `content: mailData.file.container.split(",")[1]`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the base64 data is converted to the buffer, and it is sent using the nodemailer.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

```
attachments: [
  { 
    filename: mailData.file.filename,
    content: Buffer.from((/data:.*;base64,/.test(mailData.file.container) ? mailData.file.container.split(",")[1] : mailData.file.container), 'base64'),
    contentType: mailData.file.mimetype,
  }
]
```

- If the header of base64 data (it's like `data:application/pdf;base64,`) is always included, you can also modify to `content: Buffer.from(mailData.file.container.split(",")[1], 'base64'),`.

### Reference:

- [ATTACHMENTS of nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.